# Text editor for Linux that auto-saves even new files

Tags: files, editors, text

I'm transiting from MacOS X to Linux (currently mostly using the Gnome GUI, but I like KDE also, so my question applies to any of these interfaces).

MacOS' TextEdit has a feature which allows all open (even new, 'unsaved' files) to be saved automatically. This is a very useful feature because in the event of a system crash all files would be preserved. It is also useful because one doesn't need to save the text files but keep them open instead and then just get rid of them whenever they are not needed. That is, in such a case TextEditor can just be used as a scratch pad kind of thing.

Does there exist a text editor for Linux similar to TextEdit for MacOS X in the sense that it can save even temporary (unsaved) files automatically every certain period of time?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "text editor". If you don't care for all that formatting stuff TextEdit offers, but just want plain text editing, go with *the* editor: `vim` (or `gvim`). It also autosaves unnamed buffers; reopen them after a crash with `:recover`. Being a Mac user since the 1980s, `vim` first felt strange to me, but nowadays I won't miss it anymore, even using `vim` on the iPhone ...

Comment: I'm surprised to hear that text editors don't save intermediate work. Perhaps I've been fortunate with `vi` (and latterly `vim` and OpenOffice/LibreOffice) but I'd assumed it was standard practice.

Comment: It doesn't look like `vim` can work with more than one text file (like some sort of tabs) at once, can it?

Comment: @sequence I believe `gvim` can do so, but my usual approach is either one `vi[m]` per window or occasionally `vimdiff` in a very large one.